# my pagination seems not to be working - DRF problem

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-pagination, django-viewsets

I am trying to create an endpoint that returns a list of posts. I want lets say 2 posts per page (for testing only! I know its not that big of a number to cause problem!).
here is my
**views.py**

```
class blogsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    pagination_class = pagination.CustomPagination

    
    def list(self, request):
        data = request.data
        uid = data['uid']
        context = {"user": uid}
        blogs = Posts.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(blogs, many= True, context= context)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

here is my
**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):    
    isLiked = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='check_react')
    totalLikes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_likes')
    totalComments = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_comments')

    def check_react(self, post):
        userObj = Users.objects.get(userID = self.context['user'])
        #print(type(userObj))
        
        if Likes.objects.filter(postID = post, userID = userObj).exists():
            isLiked = Likes.objects.get(postID = post, userID = userObj)
            likeObj = LikeSerializer(isLiked)
            #print('isLiked: ', likeObj.data['isLiked'])
            return (likeObj.data['isLiked'])
        return(False)
        #print(isLiked)
    
    def get_likes(self, post):
        count = Likes.objects.filter(postID = post).count()
        return count

    def get_comments(self, post):
        count = PostsComments.objects.filter(postID = post).count()
        return count

    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = '__all__'
```

and, here is my
**pagination.py**,

```
from rest_framework import pagination

class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 3
    page_query_param = 'p'
```

I am importing this class on views.py and it works as expected when I try to retrieve a list of users via **userMVS**

```
class userMVS(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    pagination_class = pagination.CustomPagination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write your list function of views as -

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    paginatedResult = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(paginatedResult, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Edits -

Suppose this is my pagination class -

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 8
    page_query_param = "pageNumber"
```

and used in this way at class level and mentioned above at list function -

```
class blogsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

then this is the url that should work

```
http://localhost:8000/urlofpostviewset/?pageNumber=passThePageNumber
```

Do read from the documents all the properties you use at CustomPagination class.

Comment: Thanks Ranu it helped limit the response, but now I am not getting those links to navigate to next, or previous pages! Can you help me in that too? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: check my updated answer if that helps you !! :)

Comment: ohh Yesss! Thanks a lot!!